# Initialise a NumPy array based on its index

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, python-itertools

I am creating a couple of multi dimensional arrays using NumPy and inititalising them based on the index as follows:

```
pos_data = []
# Some typical values
d = 2  # Could also be 3
vol_ext = (1000, 500)  # If d = 3, this will have another entry
ratio = [5.0, 8.0]  # Again, if d = 3, it will have another entry

for i in range(d):
    pos_data.append(np.zeros(vol_ext))

if d == 2:
    for y in range(vol_ext[1]):
        for x in range(vol_ext[0]):
            pos_data[0][x, y] = (x - 1.0) * ratio[0]
            pos_data[1][x, y] = (y - 1.0) * ratio[1]
elif d == 3:
    for z in range(vol_ext[2]):
        for y in range(vol_ext[1]):
            for x in range(vol_ext[0]):
                pos_data[0][x, y, z] = (x - 1.0) * ratio[0]
                pos_data[1][x, y, z] = (y - 1.0) * ratio[1]
                pos_data[2][x, y, z] = (z - 1.0) * ratio[2]
```

The looping is a bit ugly and slow as well. Additionally, if I have a 3-dimensional object then I have to have another nested loop.

I was wondering if there is a Pythonic way to generate these values as they are just based on the x, y and z indices. I tried to use the combinatorics bit from `itertools`, but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's easy with [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
pos_data = np.meshgrid(*(r * (np.arange(s) - 1.0)
                         for s, r in zip(vol_ext, ratio)), indexing='ij')
```

Comment: Nice. This is adaptable regardless of the dimension of `vol_ext`.

Comment: Thanks! This is great although took me 10 minutes to figure it out!

Comment: @Luca Yeah, actually I just realised steps 2 and 3 is exactly what `np.meshgrid` does.

Answer (score 10):

I would generate a two or three dimensional [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) of data, then scale each entry by the ratio per slice.

For the 2D case:

```
(X, Y) = np.meshgrid(np.arange(vol_ext[1]), np.arange(vol_ext[0]))
pos_data = [(Y - 1) * ratio[0], (X - 1) * ratio[1]]
```

For the 3D case:

```
(X, Y, Z) = np.meshgrid(np.arange(vol_ext[2]), np.arange(vol_ext[1]), np.arange(vol_ext[0]))
pos_data = [(Z - 1) * ratio[0], (Y - 1) * ratio[1], (X - 1) * ratio[2]]
```

## Example using your 2D data

`pos_data` has been generated by your code.  I've created a new list `pos_data2` that stores the equivalent list using the above solution:

```
In [40]: vol_ext = (1000, 500)

In [41]: (X, Y) = np.meshgrid(np.arange(vol_ext[1]), np.arange(vol_ext[0]))

In [42]: pos_data2 = [(Y - 1) * ratio[0], (X - 1) * ratio[1]]

In [43]: np.allclose(pos_data[0], pos_data2[0])
Out[43]: True

In [44]: np.allclose(pos_data[1], pos_data2[1])
Out[44]: True
```

---

## Making this adaptive based on `vol_ext`

We can combine this with a list comprehension where we can take advantage of the fact that the output of `numpy.meshgrid` is a tuple:

```
pts = [np.arange(v) for v in reversed(vol_ext)]
pos_data = [(D - 1) * R for (D, R) in zip(reversed(np.meshgrid(*pts)), ratio)]
```

The first line of code generates the range of points per desired dimension as a list.  We then use a list comprehension to compute the desired calculations per slice by iterating over each desired grid of points in the desired dimension combined with the correct ratio to apply.

## Example Run

```
In [49]: pts = [np.arange(v) for v in reversed(vol_ext)]

In [50]:  pos_data2 = [(D - 1) * R for (D, R) in zip(reversed(np.meshgrid(*pts)), ratio)]

In [51]: np.all([np.allclose(p, p2) for (p, p2) in zip(pos_data, pos_data2)])
Out[51]: True
```

The last line goes through each slice and ensures both lists align.

Comment: Thanks for this as well. Accepting the other answer as it avoids the `if` condition but this is great as well.

Comment: @Luca Not a problem. I like the other answer as it's more adaptable.

Comment: @Luca I'll edit my post it more adaptable. I'm a perfectionist.

Comment: @Luca Done... did it in two lines, not a one liner but close enough!

Comment: Thanks and great explanation as well!

Comment: @rayryeng Seems we ended up converging to basically the same solution :D I just avoided the reversing with `indexing='ij'` (which I use nearly every time I call `np.meshgrid`, I'd find the function way more intuitive if it were the default!).

Comment: @jdehesa I just learned something new as I noticed that in your answer.  Thanks for showing me!  In MATLAB, there is a function called `ndgrid`, which basically implements `meshgrid` with the `indexing=ij` enabled.  It's nice to see that the same behaviour is seen in NumPy.  I'll leave the reversed in because any more edits and we'd basically be converging to the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a couple of things to consider:

- is there a reason that `pos_data` has to be a list?
- don't have another variable (`d`) that you have to hard code, when it is always supposed to be the length of some other tuple.

With these in mind, you can solve your problem of variable numbers of for loops using `itertools.product`, which basically is just a shorthand for nested for loops. The positional args for `product` are the ranges of the loops.

My implementation is:

```
from itertools import product

vol_ext = (1000, 500)  # If d = 3, this will have another entry
ratio = [5.0, 8.0]  # Again, if d = 3, it will have another entry

pos_data_new = np.zeros((len(ratio), *vol_ext))

# now loop over each dimension in `vol_ext`. Since `product` expects
# positional arguments, we have to unpack a tuple of `range(vol)`s.
for inds in product(*(range(vol) for vol in vol_ext)):
    # inds is now a tuple, and we have to combine it with a slice in 
    # in the first dimension, and use it as an array on the right hand 
    # side to do the computation. 
    pos_data_new[(slice(None),) + inds] = (np.array(inds) - 1) * ratio
```

I don't think this will be any faster, but it certainly looks nicer.

Note that `pos_data_new` is now an array, to get it as a list in the first dimension, as per the original example, is simple enough.